# How to narrow the type of the value returned by URLSearchParams.get() to union type?

Tags: typescript, types

There is a search parameter in URL like this: `?mode=view`. The valid value of `mode` should be `'edit'` and `'view'`, so I create a `ModeTuple` type for it and convert it to union type using indexed access types `ModeTuple[number]`.

```
type ModeTuple = ['view', 'edit'];

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
const modes: ModeTuple = ['view', 'edit'];

const m1: ModeTuple[number] = modes.includes(searchParams.get('mode')) ? searchParams.get('mode') : 'view';
```

I want to check if the value of `mode` is valid using `modes.includes(...)`, then narrow the type to union type `'edit' | 'view'`.

Got error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"view" | "edit"'

It seems `Array.prototype.includes` method will NOT narrow the type from `string` to `"view" | "edit"` successfully. From the logic of the JS code, the `mode` value must be `'view'` or `'edit'`. But TSC doesn't know that.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgFQK5gDbQLxQNoDkAbgJYQDuBANFARAicAQLoDcAUOwMZwB2AzsCj8IAQwBOXABYAFCaIC2-KLl4UoAVQBKAGQDKYybPlKAFAEoOPAUIWII-AFyx7aTDnzEylGnQZM2TmtBKAUARmd4JDcsPF5UBQAjCHFmFVD7fgA6El4uDFQkflMRCWk5cUVsgHMIYFMCOyQCc3MoAH5hQ3KTGrqGpogWqGcvCgIOIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const m1: ModeTuple[number] = modes.includes(searchParams.get('mode')) ? searchParams.get('mode') : 'view';` won't work for two reasons:

1. `mode.includes` expects a `ModeTuple[number]` argument, but `searchParams.get('mode')` returns `string | null`.
2. TypeScript's flow analysis for narrowing types is limited. Even if #1 weren't an issue, it wouldn't know from `modes.includes(searchParams.get('mode'))` that a subsequent call to `searchParams.get('mode')` will return a `ModeTuple[number]` value. (Not least because not all functions are pure, so TypeScript can't assume in the general case that a function will return the same thing twice when called twice with the same arguments.)

For things like this, I like to start with a constant array, then derive the types from it:

```typescript
const modes = ["view", "edit"] as const;
type ModeTuple = typeof modes; // If you want it
type Mode = ModeTuple[number];
```

That way, the values are only listed **once** and I only have one place to change them if I need to add one, etc.

Then, you could replace your original `m1` code with:

```typescript
const m1 =
    modeString !== null && (modes as readonly string[]).includes(modeString)
    ? modeString as ModeTuple[number]
    : "view";
```

...but I don't like doing inline type assertions like that, because they're verbose and repeating them gives me multiple chances to get it wrong.

Instead, I prefer defining a single [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (aka "type guard") function that I can reuse:

```typescript
function isMode(mode: string | null): mode is Mode {
    return mode !== null && (modes as readonly string[]).includes(mode);
}
```

Then you could do:

```typescript
const modeString = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("mode");
const m1 = isMode(modeString) ? modeString : "view";
```

Or you could define a function to do it, if you may need to do it in more than one place:

```typescript
function getMode(searchParams: URLSearchParams): Mode | null {
    const mode = searchParams.get("mode");
    // Or if you didn't define `isMode`, just do the check here
    return isMode(mode) ? mode : null;
}
```

Then getting it is just:

```
const m1 = getMode(theSearchParams):
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtiAJgUwjAvDA2gIgG4CWyA7jgDQw7KIFQ4C6MAhmqJFANwBQUAngA7IYAWSTIAKgFd+AGyGY+gkADN4YiN0VDRKDCLFTZyLGElwARsgBO9bl2WSwwKAXAwCEHcgAUCFAC4YaCsCMABzGAAfGFMZGQBKQL8hD31dAG8uGGyYK2QoSSswNV0AQnRMWJkYADIamF91ZjQ8pkRwGV4gqBDwrHp4gDpQ4BlJFAhGlHjuAF8uLjZoEuQAZR7QiMqSGABVACUAGVXkJitgAAsABTOmOEmZEGAmF3BBiFPzi6Gw-O8cZI4GaLcDLOAARj0Hi8UzWG3C8RgAH4VutehFAvgiKQ7AB6XEwADyVhgxFoF2YMC0MH4eRozygQgcTleYAWzOcrmKvygMI+Z0uNysdwggQOx0+gtu90SaSE0SqMEyORgS1gyT0-K+QpFgx5-0BwJVeQKRXcnjEsMRKI1gSqcxB7HgACY9DyYWAduKTgLrtKHk8Xlz3pLvsCgA)

Comment: Thanks for advice. Yeah. `as const` will create the read-only type. Do I have to use type predicate and type cast by myself again(I know it can solve, but I prefer to let TSC infer the type)? The problem becomes when I should use type predicate or let the TSC infer the type. For this case, did I trigger TSC limited again, TSC can't infer the type?

Comment: @slideshowp2 - I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand those questions. Are you asking why `const m1: ModeTuple[number] = modes.includes(searchParams.get('mode')) ? searchParams.get('mode') : 'view';` didn't work? (I should have addressed that in the answer either way.)

Comment: Yes. I expect that after checking by using `modes.includes(..)`, the type should be narrow to the union type. But I am not sure TSC can do this. Because TSC has its limits. Its limits are a total black box for me.

Comment: @slideshowp2 - Yeah, fair enough. The flow analysis for narrowing is fairly constrained, and can't follow function calls. (I only know this from other answers here on SO. :-) ) I've updated the answer.